# how we find this results in this infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I evaluate and prove
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{2^n}= 3$$

and
how to evaluate and prove
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}= 2$$

? I know the answer thanks to Wolfram Alpha, but I'm more concerned with how I can derive that answer. It cites tests to prove that it is convergent, but my class has never learned these before. So I feel that there must be a simpler method.

In general, how can I evaluate,please give me the answer step by step with explain please  and thanks for every thing

Comment: The standard method to prove the second one is by taking the derivative of the geometric series and manipulating it a little. With that known the first is trivial

Comment: In addition to what was said in the previous comment, term-by-term integration is also sometimes useful.

Comment: See this highly-upvoted [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433924/evaluation-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n)  (Indeed, a much-duplicated problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a clever little trick
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1+\frac{S}{2}$$
$$S=1+\frac{S}{2}$$
$$S=2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$$
Consider the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n =\frac{x}{1-x}\quad\text{if}\quad |x|<1$$
Now take the derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $$
Since you are dealing with a power series, you can swap  $\Sigma$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx} (x^n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$
From this chain of equality you obtain:
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} $$
In this particular case, $x=1/2\neq0$, so you can multiply both sides by $x$:
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n $$
Plugging $x=1/2$ in the final formula, you obtain $S=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $\dfrac{2n-1}{2^n}=f(n)-f(n-1)$ where $f(m)=\dfrac{am+b}{2^m}$

$$\implies\dfrac{2n-1}{2^n}=\dfrac{an+b-2(a(n-1)+b)}{2^n}\implies2n-1=-2an+2a-b$$

Comparing the coefficients of $n$ and the constants
$$-2a=2\iff a=?, 2a-b=-1\iff b=2a+1=?$$

Now,
$$\sum_{n=1}^r\dfrac{2r-1}{2^r}=\sum_{n=1}^r(f(n)-f(n-1))=f(r)-f(0)$$